# Delete IE9 Cache and Cookies

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, caching, wininet

My app works with Web Browser Control embedding IE9.
I have changed the registry of IE to write it's cache/cookies into some own temp folder (I wanted that every instance will write it's cache and cookies to a separate location).

The writing is done perfectly (each IE instance has it's own cache folder).
From the process who runs the WBC I've added WinInet operations to delete the cache and cookies: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815718

However, after running the app and calling the clearCache functionality I can notice (via free IECacheView) that sometimes the cache deleted successfully, sometimes don't and sometimes partially succeed.

Any idea how could it happen? I'm running on Win7 x64, but can't figure out the behavior behind WinInet cache functions.

Thanks,
Guy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WinInet functionality described above - do work.
It was tested against wireshark and some other sniffers and validated the clear cache/cookies solution.

Comment: then why weren't those cache items you were talking about being deleted? do you think it has something to do with protected mode? if so, take a look at some of my latest questions.